# How to get Uri that is dynamic in the Espresso Test from My Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a form activity that contains multiple fields and pictures to capture. i am calling camera from activity with specified URI that generates dynamically for save image to specified location and get name through timemils so i want to access that URI in my espresso test that i will be able to save image to specified location with that name..

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: actully im not making static method so i found an other way to do that . im working on that

Comment: Then I can delete my answer?

Comment: no its informative someone can get idea through it that how to resolve problem